# how to activate Virtualization Technology (VT-x) on asus eee 1015pn laptop?

Tags: 64-bit, virtualization, virtual-machine, virtualbox, bios

i have this laptop: http://www.asus.com/Eee/Eee_PC/Eee_PC_1015PN/#specifications 
its running windows7 32 bit ultimate

im trying to run a 64 bit operateing system in virtual box, but it crashes at boot, also vb warns me that i have no VT-x enabled when i start the machine

i searched the bios for VT-x or vmx but i couldnt find anything, also updated my bios to revision 0701, but still couldnt find that option, they do say that my processor Intel® Atom™ N570 Processor has this technology though

does anybody has an idea how to activate VT-x ?

Answer (score 1):

Intel® Atom™ N570 doesn't support VT-x as said [here (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Atom_microprocessors#.22Pineview.22_.2845_nm.29_4) and [here (Intel)](http://ark.intel.com/products/55637).

Quote from Wikipedia:

> Neither the N550 nor N570 support Intel VT-x

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:
http://www.linuxinside.gr/content/how-unlock-and-enable-hardware-accelerated-virtualization-technology-vt-sony-vaio-laptop-and